# Grafana $__from and $__to UTC

Tags: grafana

I'm writing a query and where clause should look like this

```
    year  BETWEEN 2023 AND 2023 
AND month BETWEEN 05   AND 05 
AND day   BETWEEN 10   AND 10 
AND hour  BETWEEN 13   AND 13
```

I was trying to use `$__from` and `$__to` variables, but it simply only works with browser time.

For example `$__from:date:HH` returns hour in browser time, but `$__from:date` returns date in dashboard time.

I would expect that `$__from:date:HH` uses dashboard time as well.

Comment: Side note, your intentions about query are not clear, but I doubt that example in you question is a good idea. Consider values of from and to like `2023-06-01` and `2024-09-01`. It this case your query will be like `year BETWEEN 2023 AND 2024  AND  month BETWEEN 06 AND 09  AND  day BETWEEN 1 AND 1` and it is a **very** strange condition.

Comment: There is a [feature request](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/discussions/38175) about it, but it's rather stale. Feel free to mark you interest there.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment of writing this answer this behavior is considered expected.

There are [issue](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/68748) and [discussion](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/discussions/38175) feature requests to monitor feedback/progress on the matter of splitting date formatting to make it consistent.